# ActionScript shiftKey Not Working In Full Screen Mode?

Tags: actionscript-3, fullscreen, keyboard-events, shift

i've drawn an ellipse sprite and added it to the display list of a container, which is added to the display list of the stage.  to move the sprites with the keyboard arrows, it appears that my shiftModifier:Number variable is not working when the stage's display state is set to full screen.  shiftModifier works as it should when the stage's display state is set to Normal.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyboardDown);

function onKeyboardDown(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
    var shiftModifier:int = 1;
    if (evt.shiftKey) {shiftModifier = 10;}

    if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) {ellipse1.y -= shiftModifier;}
    if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {ellipse1.y += shiftModifier;}
    if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {ellipse1.x -= shiftModifier;}
    if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {ellipse1.x += shiftModifier;}
    }

fsm.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toggleFullScreenMode);
function toggleFullScreenMode(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
    if (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN)
        {stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;}
        else
        {stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;}
    }
```

full screen is tested in Safari and Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Flash Player 9 does not allow keyboard
>   input when displaying content in
>   full-screen mode. Flash Player 10
>   changes this, allowing for a limited
>   number of keys to be usable in
>   full-screen mode. These include Tab,
>   the Spacebar, and the (up, down, left,
>   right) arrow keys.

From [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer10_security_changes_03.html#head5). Keyboard input is disabled or restricted during fullscreen mode for security reasons (to avoid phishing, as I recall).

Comment: humm... well, in this case my arrow keys still function as they should while in full screen mode, it's just the shift key modifier doesn't.

Comment: My answer was a touch out of date. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

The shiftKey did work in flash player 10.0 while in full screen, and stopped working when I updated the flash player to 10.1. It's reported as a bug [here](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-4726), please vote to get this fixed.